# I cannot move/scroll google maps up/down/left or right as it move back tomy current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this problem that **I can't move from my current location marker point** to see the rest of the map.

For an example, let's say I am at Silicon Valley. And I can see the marker too. Everything looks perfect so far. But when I try to navigate (up, down, left, right) the map, it again brings me back to my current location.

It is **automatically and forcefully** brings me back to my current location **not allowing me to see other places around**

here is my code for the MapActivity.

```
package com.example.jananathbanuka.sliitshuttle;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class DriversMap extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
     GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
     Location lastLocation;
     LocationRequest locationRequest;
     Marker currentUserLocationMarker;
    private static final int REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE = 99;

    private Button back;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            checkUserLocationPermission();
        }

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentProfile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    public boolean checkUserLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE);
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if(googleApiClient == null){
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }else{ //permission denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        lastLocation = location;

        if(currentUserLocationMarker != null){ //set to some other location
            currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Shutter is Here");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));

        currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        float zoomLevel = 16.0f;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
//        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        String driverID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference driverDatBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference().child("On the Move");

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverDatBaseReference);
        geoFire.setLocation(driverID, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                System.out.println("================ UPDATED!!!");
            }
        });

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        disconnectDriver();
    }

    private void disconnectDriver() {
        String driverID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference driverDatBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference().child("On the Move");

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverDatBaseReference);
        geoFire.removeLocation(driverID);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me by looking at my code, why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the line `locationRequest.setInterval(1000);` you are asking to be updated of the users' location every 1 second.

This results in your `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method -where you call `mMap.moveCamera`- being called every second.

Comment: You mean since I am not moving, the new `LatLng`  are not updating but directs to the same LatLangs?

Comment: Pretty much yeah

Comment: Can you suggest me a method to move my map keeping the location intact but also updating its **LatLngs.** I mean, **how Uber allows users to move its map when he doesn't even move?**

Comment: You're already doing that, you just need to remove the `moveMap` call.

Comment: Yes thank you, but the problem is, when the map loads for the first time, **it doesn't move the camera to the current location we are residing** 
How can I solve that?

Comment: Just use a Boolean flag to detect if it's the first time.